# Mail gem error with character "&" on local part of email

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, character-encoding, actionmailer

My system's been sending emails correctly for a long time now, but yesterday I inserted the email `c&a@fakedomain.com` (fakedomain is a fake domain used here for privacy) that caused the following error:

```
550 restricted characters in address

/home/solvis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:957:in `check_response' 
/home/solvis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:926:in `getok' 
/home/solvis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:869:in `rcptto' 
/home/solvis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:850:in `block in rcptto_list' 
/home/solvis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:848:in `each' 
/home/solvis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:848:in `rcptto_list' 
/home/solvis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:663:in `send_message' 
/home/solvis/rails-deploy/server/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mail-2.6.3/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:113:in `block in deliver!' 
/home/solvis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:521:in `start' 
/home/solvis/rails-deploy/server/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mail-2.6.3/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:112:in `deliver!' 
/home/solvis/rails-deploy/server/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mail-2.6.3/lib/mail/message.rb:2141:in `do_delivery' 
/home/solvis/rails-deploy/server/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mail-2.6.3/lib/mail/message.rb:236:in `block in deliver' 
/home/solvis/rails-deploy/server/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionmailer-4.1.7/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:527:in `block in deliver_mail' 
...
```

There may be some issue with the character **&** and the mail gem. It may be some encoding problem, but I can't find the solution.

Obs: According to [this reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address), the **&** in the local part of the email is valid. The email itself is valid.

EDIT:

I tried sending mail directly from my mail server and it delivers correctly to emails with the "&" character on local part. It may be the mail gem's auto encoding of non us-ascii characters. Any hint?

Comment: "550 restricted characters in address" suggests that your email address is at least 550 characters long. I don't think this error could be caused by a single `&` character.

Comment: OW, maybe when I took that one off it was autommatically solved as the number of characters decreased. I thought 550 was the error number. Lol. I'll check that out

Comment: Oops, I misread the error message. You're completely correct, 550 is the error code. Take a look at my answer below.

Comment: I also looked at my mailing lists. None is bigger than 130 characters. So it may be the & character indeed.

Answer (score 2):

This error is coming from the SMTP server, not from the Mail gem or Action Mailer. [550 is the error code](http://www.serversmtp.com/en/error-550). It usually means that the recipient's mail server says the mailbox doesn't exist, but in this case it's rejecting the address because it doesn't like that character.

While `&` is allowed in email addresses in general, an email server is free to restrict email addresses to any characters they want.

Comment: I'll take a look at my mail server. I thought the mail gem could restrict some characters because the gems documentation says that it auto-encodes the non us-ascii characters: https://github.com/mikel/mail#current-capabilities-of-mail

Comment: I tried sending email directly from the server by command line and it worked well with the "&" character. It goes back to the mail gem auto-encoding... any hint?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. As far as I can tell the Mail gem only messes with non-US-ASCII characters, so it wouldn't touch `&`. It might be happening in Net::SMTP. I really don't know. If you have access to the server, it would probably be best to check its logs and see what characters it's actually receiving.